# Typescript property does not exist on union type

Tags: typescript

This is a situation I have ran into a couple of times, it seems like it should be fairly straightforward, but I can't find a solution that doesn't set the type to any

A function takes one of two different objects as the argument, checks which object has been received, and returns the corresponding field.

This is a simplified version of the problem, but the issue is that the two objects are only distinguishable by their properties(which have no overlap), and I can't access any of the properties, because they're not present on the other type.

```
type Obj1 = {
  message: string
}

type Obj2 = {
  text: string
}

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if (obj.message) {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

You have to narrow down the type. You can do so by using the [`in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) operator.

```
const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if ("message" in obj) {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}
```

Comment: This really suprised me, as I had tried using obj.hasOwnProperty('message'), which doesn't compile, after that I would never have thought of using the in operator.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using `in` will allow typescript to infer the correct variable type, you should avoid explicit casting

Comment: Is there any way to do this correctly in the template?

Comment: What if one of the union types is a primitive? It gives an error saying you can't use `in` with a primitive.

Comment: Can you do this in an inline conditional someway? Such as I want `const text = obj.text` (this doesn't work of course) but doing `let text` then using the conditional with `in` and assigning var seems tedious?

Comment: It's silly how TS can discriminate a type union from this but can't do this with the optional chaining operator, i.e. `(obj?.message) ? ... : ...`

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka if one of the union types is a primitive, you would also check if `typeof obj === 'object'` or `typeof obj !== 'string'` or what have you.

Comment: just found the documentation here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Comment: This seems to remove the compile error also `if (obj['message'])`

Comment: I also have the same question as @morgs32
There must be a way to access properties by always checking for conditions and creating variables using let.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the object in question is being array-indexed - `"prop" in items[idx] ? items[idx].prop : undefined` still complains about prop not existing.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the type inside the `if` keeps being the union type and it's not narrowed

Comment: Won't it be better to use a Partial?

Comment: why does the in operator work but the if doesn't ? aren't they both checking for essentially the same thing ?

Answer (score 50):

You can cast the object to either `Obj1` or `Obj2`:

```js
type Obj1 = {
  message: string
}

type Obj2 = {
  text: string
}

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if ((obj as Obj1).message) {
    return (obj as Obj1).message
  }

  return (obj as Obj2).text
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in an "Object | string" instance. Thank you!

Comment: This is bad as any. I can change it to obj as Obj2 in the first condition and app will break.

Answer (score 6):

The real answer to this problem according to what the question owner asked is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974714/11698819)

But there might be a time you are using `your defined type` with `primitive type` in this way the above solution is not going to work as the problem I faced
here is the situation

```js
type Obj1 = {
  message: string
}

const getText = (obj: Obj1 |string): string => {
  if (obj.message) {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}
```

so this scenario the solution stated above would not be perfect for you, so you might need to use `typeof` ✌️

```js
const getText = (obj: Obj1 | string): string => {
  if (typeof obj !== 'string') {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [typescript-is](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is).

```js
import { is } from 'typescript-is';

...

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if (is<Obj1>(obj)) {
    return obj1.message;
  }

  return obj2.text;
};
```

Comment: This looks great, but I'm not changing my typescript compiler just for type narrowing