# When 'Typescript property does not exist on union type' Unable to evaluate with variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, union-types

This is a follow up question to [Typescript property does not exist on union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type).

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974714/9831274) provided is to evaluate either object in the union by using the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). Which works great! Here's the example:

```js
type Obj1 = { message: string }
type Obj2 = { text: string }

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if ("message" in obj) {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}
```

However, when I try to evaluate it with a variable the same error occurs:

```js
const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
   let property = "message"

   if (property in obj) {
      return obj.message
   }

   return obj.text
}
```

Am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: With a let it won't work because then the left-hand side isn't a string literal type (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) but for some reason it doesn't work with const either.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. It doesn't seem to work with any declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does not believe that a conditional like this actually narrows the type when the key is a variable (as opposed to a literal). You can tell this because when you hover over obj in the conditional branch it reports a type of `Obj1 | Obj2`.

It does seem like the compiler should be able to figure this out and know it's safe, but the typescript compiler isn't perfect. But it's designed to err on the side of pessimism because over reporting issues is much less dangerous than allowing issues to slip into production code.

This case may seem like a big limitation. but in practice, it's not going to come up much. Your code *requires* the `message` property to be available in that conditional. Using a variable to test for that doesn't make any sense because in order to have type safe code that could only ever be one value for `property`. So you may as well use just use a literal string in the test.

---

But if you test this a lot and you want to avoid typing the sam literal over and over, you could make a simple reusable [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to do this:

```
function isObj1(obj: Obj1 | Obj2): obj is Obj1 {
    return 'message' in obj
}

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
   if (isObj1(obj)) {
      return obj.message
   }

   return obj.text
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwIxQLxQN5QLYQM54CGA5hAFxR7ABOAlgHbFQC+AUKJLIgExqZTAIAD2AUqdRi1asAZgFd6AY2C0A9vSi088ZAApViCjpQAfLgm4BKCgYSa85lBlZRXUahGBzqGgOS4CEghfTQ1bVjZWRXUqKFJgABVhYD59Q0coMx0rMRoGJlQAPkwXV1oZKF0tYzSES0sStzcPLx8oWwA6AKJSUqk+lu8wxA7BEQigA)

Comment: This is really helpful Alex. Thank you! The issue for us is the union contains 29 objects with just under 100 property variances. It would be so nice not to go case by case, but it appears that's the only route.

Comment: That sounds interesting. It's hard to build a bridge from this example to your comment here, but I would guess there is a better do to do whatever it is you're trying for here. Like have you thought of using a common property through which you can have [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)?

Comment: That is good idea too! I may write up a more thorough example to share with you. It's tricky because the objects are really typed classes (object constructors) that are created dynamically using api data. And the properties are also created dynamically from an API. Then the properties assigned using the approach above.