# TypeScript Property doesn't exists on tagged union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have defined two `interface` like this:

```
interface SignInCleanResponse {
  type: string;
  payload: {
    action: string;
  }
}

interface SignInError {
  type: string;
}
```

And now a `type` with:

```
type Action = SignInCleanResponse | SignInError;
```

Then in my code I have:

```
export default function auth (state = defaultState, action: Action) {
  return action.payload // Error
}
```

The error is:

```
TS2339: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action'. Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'SignInError'
```

I was expecting that with tagged union the `Action` would be an interface of SignInCleanResponse OR SignInError, and SignInCleanResponse has that `payload.action`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's not a tagged/discriminated union.  A [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)'s discriminant must be a literal/singleton type and not just `string`.  Consider making the code here a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE.  What is `SIGN_IN_CLEAN_RESPONSE`, etc?

Comment: It's not relevant, I will edit the code with less code.

Comment: That's just a union, not a tagged union, so you can't access properties not present in all union members unless you properly type guard; seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type) unless I'm missing something (e.g., why you think this is a discriminated union)

Comment: I fixed it. I was mixing interfaces with types, thanks.

Comment:  It's still not a discriminated/tagged union. Changing union members from types to interfaces does not change this. If you want a discriminated union, make `type` in each union member a singleton, say a string literal type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DWKlZw). If you *don't* want a discriminated union, you need to do some other form of type guarding to narrow from the union, because you cannot just access properties of unions **unless they are common to all members**. I don't know how to communicate this better. Can you elaborate how this differs from the linked question above?

Comment: The general behavior for a union is that you cannot access a property unless it is defined on **ALL** members of the union.  So you can't access `action.payload` because `SignInError` doesn't have that property.  It's easy to fix it such that you can access `action.payload`, but it might be `undefined`.  Is that sufficient for you?  One way is to add `payload?: never` to `SignInError`.