# Typescript iterate and filter an array of different types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does anyone know how can i filter and get numbers greater than 250 in an array consisting of two different types i.e

```
interface Foo {
    myNumber: number
}

interface Bar {
    present: boolean
}

const myArray : (Foo | Bar)[] = [{myNumber: 200}, {myNumber:600}, {myNumber:450}, {present: true}]

myArray.filter((it: Foo|Bar) => it?.myNumber >= 250)
```

The error i am getting is "Property 'myNumber' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'."

i know the reason behind the error message however can't think of a straight forward solution atm.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIC2AngHICuRARtAFzIhW1S4C%20uuoksiKAQnCg58hAA5QIAZwjgG1TABsIcEO04J0IKWGIkAglChwSyBgAoMWAD7JBUAJQBtALrIAvMifZSlGvWQAJgAGYLYAGhxfZnoANlCIqPIYqDoAFgBWMMjsCWlZMAYwKAoINhdOUkNjEgA6GGBFHnNzYEK0TGt7Bw8APmQ2gH5a6P9hXs9ArIdcIA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript property does not exist on union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type)

Comment: Why are you using `Foo` & `Bar`? you could have both in one interface right?

Comment: @TobiasS. yeah, tried that i.e myArray.filter((it: Foo|Bar) => "myNumber" in it ? it.myNumber >= 250 : false),  it does solve the problem. i was looking more for an elegant solution if there is any using filters.

Comment: @Mbistami yes we can. Howver, i won't -> legacy code

Comment: @user2083529 just posted an answer with one interface

Comment: The simplest way is to remove the type annotations from the array and from the filter callback parameter. The compiler is smarter than you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIC2AngHICuRARtAFzIhW1S4C+uuoksiKAQnCg58hAA5QIAZwjgG1TABsIcEO04J0IKWGIkAglChwSyALzIA2tj2Ua9ZACYADM+RsANDlvMHANld3LxtSOxYGABYAVjdPbwlpWTAGMCgKFDYAXU5SQ2MSADoYYEUeAApgXTMAPmRKgtDfYQB+ZuQ3aotHGIBKIA

Comment: @AluanHaddad or i can remove all the types, use unknown or any type. or perhaps better will be to get rid of the whole typescript and use javascript :D

Comment: You don't understand. The types are there whether you write them down or not. That's how the language works, via inference and structurally.

Comment: @AluanHaddad True, but type inference is prone to typos in your suggested solution. You could put any other type in the array without getting any error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are right, however the linter set up in the project won't let me use instances without defining its type. i can disable it for the specific part fo code block however, will wait if there is an elegant solution.

Comment: It certainly depends on what your intentions are any bit of code. It's usually wise to annotate the parameters of non inline functions, because they cannot be inferred, and perhaps the return types of exported functions. Annotating the parameters of inline callbacks, as in `filter((x: number) => {})`, is unnecessary and can actually lead to obscure bugs.

Comment: @user2083529 linters are important and you should customize them to your preferences but it's typical these days for linters to ship with rules that overlap with or conflict with the language proper. This can make learning TypeScript difficult in the beginning especially if you have a lot of preset 3rd party lint rules that you've adopted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're using two different interfaces but,
In my opinion, it can be done in one `interface` using `optional fields`.
And this is how it looks with one interface

```js
interface Foo {
    myNumber?: number,
    present?: boolean
}

const myArray : (Foo)[] = [{myNumber: 200}, {myNumber:600}, {myNumber:450}, {present: true}]

console.log(myArray.filter((it: Foo) => it?.myNumber && it?.myNumber >= 250))
```

let me know if you **REALLY** need two interfaces I can update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Letting TS infer the type of the array as Aluan Haddad suggested in the comments is certainly one way. However, I assume you want to keep the array typed as `Foo | Bar` to make sure the array doesn't contain anything else.

You can define the infered type on your own as

```
type FooOrBar = (Foo & {
    [Key in keyof Bar]?: never;
}) | (Bar & {
    [Key in keyof Foo]?: never;
});
```

And use this type for `it`:

```
myArray.filter((it: FooOrBar) => it.myNumber !== undefined && it?.myNumber > 250);
```

Or maybe avoid the `undefined`-check with

```
myArray.filter((it: FooOrBar) => Number(it?.myNumber) > 250);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIC2AngHICuRARtAFzIhW1S4C+uuoksiKAQnCg58hAA5QIAZwjgG1TABsIcEO04J0IKWGIkAglChwSDABQYsAH2SCoASgDaAXWQBeZI+x7KNesgAmAAYg5DYAGhwfZn8ANhCwyO9SXxYGABYAVlCIqIlpWTAGMCgKFDZnTjASMRRLAHkoO3dkC0xkADIRQk8AaQgSZFBkAGsB9BhbIWcAfgYQCAA3aABudntkGzNmrrwex37B4bGSCbRMWfml1fW13FJDYxIAOhhgRR4zM2Ai8-RGuwbNwAPiGYGeKRiwg6XR+EPIUOQoIC2XsKyAA)