# Mutually exclusive types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I defined these next types in my code:

```ts
type base_info = {
  id?: number,
  name: string,
  email: string
}

type week_info = {
  days_selected?: string[]
}

type workout_info = {
  workout_intensity?: number
}
```

Then, i needed a type that would either be exclusively of `base_info` AND `week_info`, or exclusively of `base_info` AND `workout_info`.

So, i defined this next type:

```ts
type system_info = base_info & ( week_info | workout_info)
```

However, when i define this variable:

```ts
const check: system_info = {
  name: "Billy",
  email: "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

And then try to update:

`check.days_selected: ["Monday"]`

I get a red line error that states:
*"Property days_selected does not exist on type system_info"*
*"Property days_selected does not exist on type base_info & workout_info"*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to narrow the type. You can take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type/58974714#58974714

Comment: unions don't really work this way; ideally you'd narrow `check` to either union member before trying to modify its properties.  The compiler can't narrow `check` when you set a property, so even if you represent an exclusive union as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbaeEN) the compiler won't catch mistakes like this.  I'd suggest changing to creating `check` already narrowed, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAgq8w) maybe.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've told TypeScript that your `check` variable is of type `system_info`. Combining your types into one just for ease of reference here, that looks like this:

```js
type system_info = {
  id?: number,
  name: string,
  email: string
} & (
  {
    days_selected?: string[]
  } | {
    workout_intensity?: number
  }
);
```

So TypeScript knows that `check` has `name` and `email` properties, and that it might have an `id` property, but with the information it has TypeScript can't tell if `check` has a `days_selected` property or a `workout_intensity` property. So if you try to access either of those properties on it that's exactly what TypeScript will complain about - you shouldn't access a property that doesn't exist.

Of course, if you try to access a property that doesn't exist during runtime, you'll just end up with `undefined`, and you might think "isn't that just like an optional property?" but it's not quite the same. Remember, TypeScript is an annotation tool that's meant to enhance your IDE, and one of those enhancements is to help catch errors while writing code. For example, trying to access properties that haven't been defined on your type definition, which could indicate a typo or similar mistake. That's why TypeScript calls this out as an error.

In order to put your `check` variable into a context where TypeScript can know that property exists, you need to implement some conditional code that will `narrow` its type in runtime, since that's the only point where you'll really be able to check what properties exist on an object like this.

One way you can do this is by [using the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing). For example:

```js
type base_info = {
  id?: number,
  name: string,
  email: string
}

type week_info = {
  days_selected?: string[]
}

type workout_info = {
  workout_intensity?: number
}

type system_info = base_info & ( week_info | workout_info)

const check: system_info = {
  name: "Billy",
  email: "abc@gmail.com"
}

if ('days_selected' in check) {
    // TypeScript now knows that `check.days_selected` is `string[] | undefined` 
    check.days_selected = ["Monday"];
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARghgZwgfQJYDsBmB7KBeKAbwFgAoKKVAEwH4AuKdAVwFsYIAnAGjIvThYQGCYBwwBzHuSgQWcVABthoiWQC+ZMqEhQA7hAgBrNFlwES0qnBAJkSBRADGwCLWVj04gNoBddZtJtaF1sDkNsJmATHHwiXj1Q8MiTF3QEVFB6RlZ2Dn9SLXBoBBsXFmizWEQUDBiAMigACj0DY1rcAB8EsIio9oBKAMdsNOAoRwALJ0NhUtkK2Is+ASEoACIAIUUFEDWpCll5JXW4GEcAAXE5RQA6YZY1-LJUTCaAcisbOwgHZ1c3yjocZTRyGfpxUgASAA9NCoAAVIoAZUcYjAY3Q2F0UEMmN0CCgwAmcDGAANJtMbp9bPYnC4qKTKATSSIPN4fFAukx0FQIJgMK5GWRIRTQVTrDSfnTXLEvGsALIjT5rHwAbnyQA)

Union types that can be narrowed like this are referred to as [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Narrowing via the `in` operator isn't the only way to perform type narrowing, though it is likely the easiest way to do it here. If you're interested in learning more about this concept in TypeScript (and sorry if you're already familiar with it, but others reading this answer may not be) you might like to read the [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) page of the TypeScript Handbook.

Another caveat is that the `in` check I've suggested might not work. After all, `days_selected` is an optional property, so it might not exist yet. It's up to you how you'd like to handle this, it really depends on the details of exactly what you're trying to accomplish. If you find yourself in a situation where you'd like to tell TypeScript to treat `check` as though you know its type is the version with a `days_selected` property, you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to do this.

However, be aware that type assertions are best avoided where possible. They serve a necessary purpose in TypeScript where you may need to provide additional information to the TypeScript compiler, but they can also be dangerous because if they're not based on good assumptions then they can break your type system. If you decide you do need to use a type assertion, I find it's a helpful practice to always leave a comment explaining the reason for using a type assertion, and the assumption(s) underlying it.